# Profile page link like in the Facebook profile

Tags: php, facebook, user-profile

Any one could help me to set the profile page like in the facebook profile page

Ex: www.facebook.com/username

I want to set the like my website address/username.Is it possible in php.

Comment: If you would just google it half a second. Try googling *URL Rewriting*

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess, a realy simple ussage could be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^./(.*)/$ index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Than if the person will type http://www.example.com/nobody/
the `$_GET['username']` will be filled with `nobody`

Check out [this beginners tutorial](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/) on `.htaccess`